# Upload de imagem AngularJS com servidor Java

Tags: java, upload, angularjs

Estou com um problema em fazer um upload de imagem web, estou usando o *angular file upload*, quando realizo o upload ele grava a imagem na pasta *Frame -> imagens* do navegador, e quando vou ler o `inputStream` lá no meu servidor ele não retorna a imagem. Como resolver o problema?

Comment: Cleiton, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Acho que você precisa elaborar um pouco melhor sua pergunta. Não vejo como ajudar a não ser fazer inúmeras conjecturas. Por exemplo, você disse que a imagem é gravada, mas se você abrir ela num editor ela está normal? O arquivo fica com o tamanho igual ao original? Há alguma mensagem no console? Como é o código onde você abre o InputStream?

Comment: Obrigado. Então o caso e o seguinte no cliente a imagem aparece mas eu preciso pegar a imagem para gravar no servidor, mas o problema e que não consigo la no servidor pegar a imagem, consigo pegar nome da imagem, tamanho, mas o problema está em pegar por exemplo o _byte_ da imagem e converter para imagem no servidor... Ficou mais claro a minha duvida ?

Comment: Ajudou um pouco, mas entenda que existem muitas formas diferentes de recuperar um upload em Java (Spring, Apache Commons File Upload, PrimeFaces, etc). Seria bom você postar o código do método onde faz isso.

Comment: Estou usando o Commons, la vai o código `if (req.getHeader("Content-Type") != null
     && req.getHeader("Content-Type").startsWith(
       "multipart/form-data")) {
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);` ai  utilizo ` while (iterator.hasNext()) { FileItemStream item = iterator.next();` a estava tentando obter a imagem através do inputStream assim : `if (item.getName() != null) {

      File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/"    + item.getName());`

Comment: Essa e a parte onde tento pegar o _inputStream_ e transformar em imagem `byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

      OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(
        new File(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath()));

      System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
      int read = 0;

      System.out.println(req.getInputStream().toString());
      
      while ((read = req.getInputStream().read(bytes)) != -1) {
       
       outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);

}  outpuStream.flush();    outpuStream.close();`

Comment: @CleitonMigliorini por favor, faça uma edição na sua pergunta para colocar o código desses comentários. Fica confuso colocar como comentário. Depois apague eles. Aqui é diferente de um fórum.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que há um equívoco no seu código. Primeiro você recupera um item assim:

```java
FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
```

Depois, ao ler os bytes do arquivo, você recupera o `InputStream` geral da requisição:

```java
while ((read = req.getInputStream().read(bytes)) != -1) { ... }
```

No entanto, o código deveria recuperar o `InputStream` do item, assim:

```java
InputStream inputStream = item.openStream();
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) { ... }
```

Afinal, a requisição poderia ter mais campos e arquivos, não é mesmo?

Enfim, refatorei um pouco o código que você postou nos comentários e cheguei a isso:

```java
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {

    FileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
    FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
        if (item.getName() != null) {

            File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + item.getName());

            byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
            int read = 0;
            OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            InputStream inputStream = item.openStream();
            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Realmente aquela chamada do inputStream está errada, estava testando e acabei esquecendo mas com as mudanças os erros continuam o mesmo. _SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [file_upload] in context with path [/UploadImagem] threw exception [org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream$ItemSkippedException] with root cause
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream$ItemSkippedException
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl.openStream(FileUploadBase.java:855)_ Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Ao meu ver o inputStream não está retornando a imagem

Comment: `ItemSkippedException` é lançado quando você tenta acessar o `InputStream` após chamar o `ext` para o próximo Stream. Por acaso você está listando os itens para **depois** tentar ler os bytes?

Comment: não, já tenta ler os bytes direto